# ThreadStatic in async/await - LogicalCallContext doesn't flow outside of async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to implement a reentrant `Monitor`-like primitive for async/await.

```
    public async Task<DisposableAction> LockAsync()
    {
        // await current executing task;
        // ...
        if (_reentrant)
        {
            var list = CallContext.LogicalGetData(CallContextListName) as HashSet<AsyncLock>;
            if (list != null && list.Contains(this)) return new DisposableAction();

            list = list ?? new HashSet<AsyncLock>();
            list.Add(this);
            CallContext.LogicalSetData(CallContextListName, list);
        }
        // acquire a "lock" and return IDisposable that removes from list
        // ...
    }
```

The calling code looks like:

```
 using (await _lock.LockAsync())
 {
     // ...
     return await PossibleRecursiveMethod();
 }
```

I'm debugging this and it looks like the *CallContextListName* object is present in `CallContext` inside `LockAsync` method but disappears when execution reaches the first statement inside `using` block.

I'm doing this on .NET 4.5.2 so `LogicalCallContext` should work I guess. So what's wrong? How it should be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was in that `LogicalCallContext` is only passed deeper so when the execution returns from `LockAsync` the stored context is lost.

I ended up wrapping `LockAsync` with non-async method version:

```
    public Task<DisposableAction> EnterAsync()
    {
        container = new Container(); // class
        // I'm using AsyncLocal instead of LogicalCallContext but it's pretty much the same thing
        _entered.Value = container;            
        return EnterAsync(container);
    }


    async Task<DisposableAction> EnterAsync(Container container)
    {
         // real work
    }
```

This way `LogicalCallContext` is set on the same async level as a caller method and not lost with return.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to implement a reentrant Monitor-like primitive for async/await.

This is almost certainly the wrong solution for your problem. [Reentrant locks cause a ton of very subtle problems](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html) (detailed on my blog) and are usually indicative of a poor design. There's only one use case for reentrant locks:

> recursive locks are useful in recursive algorithms with parallel characteristics where fine-grained locking of a shared data structure is required for performance reasons.

I'm not sure if *asynchronous* reentrant locks would ever have a valid use case. That said, I have implemented them as a proof-of-concept [based on my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/Source/Unit%20Tests/AdvancedExamples/RecursiveAsyncLockExample.cs).

Regarding the details of your problem, there are actually *two* problems with the code:

1. You should [only store immutable data in the logical call context](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) (as I describe on my blog).
2. "Async local" data only flows *down* asynchronous calls. It cannot flow "up". My proof-of-concept sidesteps this by only updating the logical call context when the asynchronous lock acquisition *completes* (using a custom awaitable).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one implementation that I wrote:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReentrantAsyncLock/

This is the only thing I've seen that gives you all three of these at the same time:

- Asynchronicity
- Reentrance
- Mutual exclusion

You'll notice that the second two of those are what `Monitor.Enter`/`lock` gives you. I think it's valid to call `ReentrantAsyncLock` the async equivalent.

Study the code to see how it works. You'll also notice that it uses `ExecutionContext` (which flows down through async calls) to enable reentrance. And to more directly answer your question, it makes a local scope object escape out into the calling context ("flow outside of async method") by *synchronously* putting it into the `ExecutionContext` (via an `AsyncLocal`). This line here is invoked *synchronously*:

https://github.com/matthew-a-thomas/cs-reentrant-async-lock/blob/d103d21b1b8f5fb755ee61618a27479a5d793e98/ReentrantAsyncLock/ReentrantAsyncLock.cs#L100

Here's how you use it:

```cs
var asyncLock = new ReentrantAsyncLock();
var raceCondition = 0;
// You can acquire the lock asynchronously
await using (await asyncLock.LockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // The lock is reentrant
            await using (await asyncLock.LockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
            {
                // The lock provides mutual exclusion
                raceCondition++;
            }
        }),
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await using (await asyncLock.LockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
            {
                raceCondition++;
            }
        })
    );
}
Assert.Equal(2, raceCondition);
```

This is certainly not the first attempt at doing this. But like I said it's the only correct attempt that I've seen so far. Some other implementations will deadlock trying to re-enter the lock in one of the
`Task.Run` calls. Others will not actually provide mutual exclusion and the
`raceCondition` variable will sometimes equal 1 instead of 2:

- [Stephen Cleary's POC](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/v4/Source/Unit%20Tests/AdvancedExamples/RecursiveAsyncLockExample.cs) does not provide mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vLKyCX
- [NeoSmart.AsyncLock](https://github.com/neosmart/AsyncLock) does not provide reentrance with mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CkK674
- [Flettu](https://github.com/mysteryjeans/Flettu/) sometimes does not provide reentrance, sometimes throws a semaphore count exception, or otherwise does not provide mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o0c7j7
- [CellWars.Threading.AsyncLock](https://github.com/jasonkuo41/CellWars.Threading.AsyncLock) does not provide mutual exclusion: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tz38lN